# Clear browsing history from specific site on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, cache, history

I am using Chrome version 114.0.5735.110. I am trying to remove the history, cache, and cookies of a particular website. Google [gives](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cdelete-cookies-from-a-site) the following instructions:

[image]

However, there is no longer such an option. These are the options:

[image]

and when I click on "Clear browsing history", I have only options regarding my entire history and cache, and no option for choosing a website:

[image]

Google One Support tells me that there is no longer such an option. THIS IS RIDICULUS. I truly believe that the representative did not know what he is talking about.

Any idea?

Answer (score 8):

This is still possible by listing the wanted elements, selecting
the specific site in the search box, selecting all elements
and deleting.

**Clear Browsing history for a site**

- Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to display the history
- Type the website name in the search field at the top to show only it
- Click the selection box of the first item in the list
- Scroll to the end of the list
- Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click the selection box of the last item
  in the list to select all items
- Type <kbd>Del</kbd> and the deed is done.

**Clear cookies for a site**

- Go to
  *Settings > Privacy and Security> Site Settings > Cookies and site data > See all cookies and site data*
- Enter the site name in the search box
- Click the "Trashcan" icon to the right of the site name.

Comment: Shift+click was the bit I was missing, thank you!

Comment: It seems you can only do 150 at a time this way.